# Tutorial 5 Step 5 loading error: unable to load web part script resources

Tags: spfx-webparts

When testing the jquery webpart, got loading error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is the hosted version of the workbench, make sure you are allowing mixed mode requests (http requests from an https page)

Also - why is it looking for node-mudules ?  It should be node_modules (notice the u in module rather than an o and a - rather than an _)

Did you edit something by hand?  I'd do a search in your directory for mudule

Comment: Thank you Pat! It was typo in config.json, should be "node_modules". Corrected it and it works now :-)